# Why cant I assign array of value type into object array variable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, roslyn

Assignment into `a` is OK, assignment into `b` causes compilation error, why?

```
Dim a As Object() = { 1 }
Dim b As Object() = ({ 1 })
```

Error message is:

> BC30333   Value of type 'Integer()' cannot be converted to 'Object()' because 'Integer' is not a reference type.

Comment: It's because `Integer is not a reference type`. There is no issue if you try it with `String`.

Comment: It infers the type into an `Integer`.

Comment: @MichalHosala, my mistake, sorry about that.

Comment: If you are putting integers into it, why declare the array as `Object()` at all?

Comment: @AFriend but there is an int in the first case as well (assignment into a) and it is no problem.

Comment: Would the downvoter mind to state what he/she doesn't like about this question? It is well formed and clearly describes what I am asking for.

Comment: @Plutonix this is stripped down version just to demonstrate the issue I am handling, this code on its own doesnt make any sense, you are right. What we are trying to achieve is to develop automated tool to convert VBScript to VB.NET and as part of it we run strong typing, which, based on what is getting assigned into variable tries to figure out its type. In one case variable was gettign assigned both array of strings and array of longs and converted VB.NET code didn't compile because our automated tool typed it as array of obejcts, because of a conflict between array of strings anf longs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example works because it infers and creates an `Object` array.

However in the second example the part within the parentheses is evaluated first and is inferred to an `Integer` array, then it tries to assign that to `b` (which of course doesn't work, since you cannot convert whole arrays like that).

---

According to the MSDN article [***Local Type Inference***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384937.aspx) `Option Infer` will make the compiler decide the type based on what value you give a variable:

> The compiler infers the type of the variable from the type of the initialization expression.

I think I've figured it out:

Because everything has to be done correctly the parentheses must be evaluated first, *then* the rest of the statement. The compiler doesn't know if you are later trying to do anything more with the array inside the parentheses until it has evaluated the whole statement. Because of this it assumes you want an integer array.

In the first example there are no parentheses, thus the whole statement can be evaluated directly *which is expected to result in an object array*. When the compiler sees that it needs to perform an implicit conversion it chooses `Object()`, since that's what you said you wanted and because that is the only thing it can evaluate.

Comment: So you are basically saying that implicitly typed array which is not wrapped in parentheses never has type on its own and it always depends on a context? If that is true, then I think it implies that this [roslyn bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11933) which I started is somehow invalid, do you agree?

Comment: @MichalHosala : I'm not good with Roslyn, but in general compilers tend to evaluate parentheses first (after all, that's how proper math should be done).

Comment: You are right, of course, I just thought that `{ 1 }` has type on its own, regardless the parentheses.

Comment: @MichalHosala : I don't think it has its own type, no. The compiler determines (infers) the type at compile-time/runtime. Which in this case are `Object()` and `Integer()`.

Comment: Hm, ok, I thought that VB.NET analogy of C# code `new[] { 1 }` would be `{ 1 }`, but it obviously isn't so as `new[] { 1 }` has type on its own. Seems like `({ 1 })` behaves way more similarly.

Comment: @MichalHosala : I don't understand... Neither should have their own type. I rather think it has got to do with how the compiler decides to interpret them. What's the thing with `new[] { 1 }` then?

Comment: @MichalHosala : I think I've figured out why the compiler acts like it does. Please see the update on my answer.

Comment: As for what is the thing with `new[] { 1 }`, it has type on its own, hence `object[] a = new[] { 1 }` would result in a compiler error. Closest analogy of `Dim a As Object() = { 1 }` in a C# world would be `object[] a = { 1 }` I guess. And analogy of `Dim a = { 1 }` doesn't exist in C# world as `var a = { 1 }` won't compile. So I just got a little mind-boggled there :)

Answer (score 0):

To literally answer the question in the title - because an array of value types literally just contains a contiguous block of memory holding each value type, but an array of *objects* consists of a contiguous block of memory holding *object references*.

You can, of course, convert a value type into an object reference by *boxing*. But there's no guarantee that an object reference and a value type occupy the same amount of memory and, even if there were, that single block of contiguous memory can't hold both the value type *and* an object reference simultaneously.

If you do need to perform such an "assignment", a new array has to be allocated *somehow* (e.g. maybe via LINQs `Cast` and `ToArray` methods) and, once created, the two arrays are then completely independent - changes to values in  one will not be reflected by changes to the boxed values in the other.

Comment: Yes, you are answering the question from the title, but not with regards to the rest of question description.